# Can macOS support greater than 2x Retina (for a small 4K screen)?

Tags: display, resolution, multi-touch

I'm interested in a 4K portable monitor which is 14" in size.

I believe it is mainly intended for use with iOS/Android, however it does say it supports Mac/Win.

The concern I have is that even at the familiar maximum 2x scaling, which we call Retina resolution, 14" at "looks like" 1920x1080 will result in very small UI.

To compound the problem in this case, this display is touch, too; which is likely to make finger accuracy an issue.

Does or can macOS support greater than 2x Retina? How are the supported resolutions for a display defined? Is this something Apple does, or does the manufacturer do it; can a user adjust it without going too low level?

Comment: What monitor? macOS does not support touch so it will (hopefully) ignore the touch capabilities of the monitor - finger accuracy won't matter (so long as you use your touchpad or mouse,

Answer (score 0):

While macOS currently does not support scaling to more than 2x, you can always run a display at less than native resolution. For example, run the display at 2560x1440 while using 2x, so the size of the UI would be equivalent to 1280x720. This should still look perfectly fine on a small screen with such high resolution.

The display tells the Mac which resolutions it supports. macOS may not show all of them in System Preferences, but the important ones are usually there.